# Which datatype for weight and lengths?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to create a table with following columns:

- weight
- grams
- length
- height

Which datatype should I use for these? You can enter values like 100.50m or 10.50

I was considering `DECIMAL(10,2)` but I don't know if it is the right datatype to use.

Comment: Why weight  and grams ?

Comment: How many digits do you need before the decimal point and how many after the decimal point? That answer is the answer to your question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens its different, Idk what the user give to input when he enter the weight, some use 100.50, other do 10.295

Comment: You can use int using mm milligrams, or any other unit you need, the digits you can extract by dividing by 100 1000 ...

Comment: It's not about what the user gives you as input, it's about what you (your application) accepts as input. How many decimals do you accept?

Comment: You might want to also take a look at [postgresql-unit](https://github.com/df7cb/postgresql-unit).

Comment: Either 1) accept "anything" from the user and store as `text`, or 2) validate the input and convert to a standard unit if it contains both quantity and unit or 3) accept two inputs per field: quantity and units, with validation on both. I would go with 3) and store both as text so you can faithfully re-render user input.

Comment: @Bohemian thanks, but why I should store it as text instead of varchar ?

Comment: @newstacker `text` *is* `varchar` - there's no practical difference.